# How Can I Export/ Backup/ Migrate All Extensions from one Chromium based browser to another?

Tags: backup, google-chrome-extensions, chromium, export

Im not using the official Google Chrome nor and not able to use its Sync feature.

Chromium used to be good and flexible, you could just copy the "extensions" folder and it would work.. I dont know why they disabled that ability??  It must be a conspiracy...

The only way I discovered to do this nowadays (Theoretically) is by automatically ( not one by one) packing my existing extensions to .crx's through this command I found on stack exchange:

```
[path]\chrome.exe --pack-extension=c:\myext --pack-extension-key=c:\myext.pem --no-message-box
```

Now, I dont know how to code or make commands, So I dont know how to apply this command to all my extensions..

1. Run CMD
2. ???

Help?

[Edit] : 
 Forgot to mention -  The attempt to transfer the extenstions folder was from an INSTALLED chrome browser to a PORTABLE Brave browser, so every time I copy the extensions' folders (name is like "aaocbkeamabaniccpnbapflopmcnpjbg" for example) and paste them inside Brave's same directory, IT WOULD GET AUTOMATICALLY DELETED.. maybe Im doing something wrong?

Comment: You can also export an extension in `chrome://extensions/`, enable Developer mode and click Pack extension. To install a `.crx` file, drag and drop it onto an open Chrome browser.

Comment: Sorry, I havent been very thorough in my explanation.. What I want is an automatic way to do just that, for like 100+ extensions... Manually would take too much time..

Comment: Yes yes yes, I have the same problem on the Arc Browser in MacOS. Chromium changed something and now it's super hard. I don't just want to share extensions, I need to copy the settings of all extensions as well. Even Google's sync feature wouldn't be sufficient for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach seems promising (although I have not tried it):

- **Get all extension IDs**
  Enter `chrome://system` and click next to "extensions" the button of "Expand...".
  Select and copy all extension IDs and names to a text file.
  This may look like:

  ```
  aapocclcgogkmnckokdopfmhonfmgoek : Slides : version 0_10
  ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb : Web Store : version 0_2
  aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake : Docs : version 0_10
  ```
- **Convert to URLs**
  Use a text editor to convert all the lines to this format:

  ```
  https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=49.0&x=id%3D<Extension_ID>%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc
  ```

  Where `<Extension_ID>` is the above ID and `prodversion` is your Chrome version.
  Each URL will download the matching extension's `.crx` file from the Google Store.
- **Download the .crx files**
  Use a bulk downloader to read the list and download all the `.crx` files.
- **Install the extensions**
  Open Chrome to the page of `chrome://extensions` and drag-drop into it
  all the `.crx` files.

Comment: Means you have to install them all over again, unless I'm mistaken... :-) Plus, extensions are frequently updated in the background, so what if one needs updating and you're installing an obsolete .crx file?

Comment: @Didier: Yes, transfer is the same as installation. An outdated extension will be updated automatically sooner or later.

Comment: I took "transfer" to mean "copy-paste the existing extensions from one location to another, along with all the other files the app needs to work", without the need to go to the Google Store, look them up one by one, regardless of the install method.

Comment: @Didier: Your understanding should be expressed in your answer, not in comments on mine.

Comment: I posted it several times already, and insisted on the fact that though a whole profile can be copied and pasted in a new PC, the extensions themselves had to be reinstalled every time.

Comment: @harrymc That is a clever way.. but to convert 100s of extensions to Urls manually will take too much time...

Comment: This is not manual if you have the right software. The text editor can do that with one regex replace (or a macro), and the bulk downloader will only be called once.

Comment: Ok . Awesome...

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: list them all in Nirsoft's [Browser AddOns View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_addons_view.html), and reinstall one-by-one, which takes a few minutes. Advantages of this approach is that it doesn't bring along legacy data from previously uninstalled add-ons, and that you can yous the list for Firefox and other browsers that take these extensions.

Comment: Exporting the whole profile will only work to some extent: bookmarks will be transferred, but not the extensions, because they're attributed a UID when installed, that has to be on par with the browser's. I use a portable version of Slimjet that I keep on a network drive for ease of use. Everytime I run it on a different PC, it says it defaulted to a clean profile, and I have to reinstall the extentions on the new PC. They're stored in my user profile AppData folder.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser install takes on a UID composed of a long series of digits. Extensions you install on your copy of, say, Chrome, will be linked to this UID, even if you choose a portable version of the browser, because they'll be listed in your AppData folder as bearing that UID.

You'll have to reinstall them every time with each new copy of the browser you install on other computers, with the exception of those hard-coded with the program executable: Opera or Slimjet offer ad-blocking out of the box, and this functionality is bundled with the program itself; you don't need to go to the Google Store to install third-parties.

Comment: Goddamit someone HAS to come up with a solution!

Comment: can we also copy this UID to the new machine?